# Objective-C equivalent for Smalltalk's at: aKey ifAbsentPut: aBlock?

Tags: objective-c, smalltalk, sortedcollection

Consider the following code:

```
rankedGames at: rank ifAbsentPut: [SortedCollection sortBlock: [:one :two | one name < two name]].
```

I've only seen this "convenience" method used a couple of times in Smalltalk code, and then there is that SortedCollection there with no direct Obj-C equivalent. What is the Objective-C equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Objective-C equivalent?

There isn't a direct equivalent. `NSMutableArray` gives you an *ordered* collection that can be sorted, so that's probably the closest to `SortedCollection`. I don't know of a single-line equivalent of `at:ifAbsentPut:`, so you'd normally do that in a few lines:

```
// assume rankedGames is an array of mutable arrays
NSMutableArray *games = rankedGames[rank];
if (games == nil) {
    games = [NSMutableArray array];
}
```

Comment: So I was on the right track, but the solution is much more complex than Smalltalk. I'll experiment.